# Check if a field array is empty?

Tags: php, arrays

I want if value field `txtname` was  empty echo `It is ok` but it don't work in my code(if field was empty and click on button you see output with `print_r(...)`), Please see my demo and my code. what do I do?

**Demo:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/FNWcIs

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="txtname[]">
    <button>Click Me</button>
</form>
<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        $txtname = $_POST['txtname'];
        if (!empty($txtname)) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($txtname); // Output this is: Array ( [0] => )
        } else {
            echo 'it is ok';
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)` what do you get there?

Comment: @ Truth - See here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UXe1ZC and click on button `Click Me`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way it works if you are not intending to pass one value to the variable $txtname

`

```
    $txtname       = $_POST['txtname'];
    if($txtname[0]){
        echo '<pre>';
                print_r($txtname); // Output this is: Array ( [0] => )
            }else{
                echo 'it is ok';
            }
}
```

?>`

Answer (score 2):

change input field name to txtname like show below.

```
<input name="txtname">
```

Or if you want to use array of textboxes try below code.

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="txtname[]">
    <input name="txtname[]">
    <input name="txtname[]">
    <button>Click Me</button>
</form>
<?php
    if($_POST){
        $txtname       = $_POST['txtname'];

            foreach($txtname   as $key=>$value)
            {
                if(!empty($value)){
                    echo '<br>'.$value; // Output this is: Array ( [0] => )
                }else{
                    echo '<br>it is ok';
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$txtname` or (`$_POST['txtname']`) is an array with one element. Even that element is empty, [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) returns `TRUE` for any array that has one or more elements.

That should explain the behavior of your code.

To achieve what you're looking for, change the HTML:

From:

```
<input name="txtname[]">
```

To:

```
<input name="txtname">
```

If you don't use the brackets, it will be a string. And `empty` will return `FALSE` if it is empty. See [Variables From External Sources <sup>PHP Manual</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).